# git-lfs: Can I create a bare repo that contains the binaries and then clone from that? (So final client bypasses LFS server)

Tags: git, git-lfs

Due to forces beyond my control, I am trying to set up some remote git repos for pulling different versions of code (git bundle is not appropriate for this).  All this is on windows networks.

So basically:

```
[Github + LFS]       <=== "origin"
     V
     V  (periodic sync via git fetch --all)
     V
[local_bare.repo]    <=== Cloned bare, then periodic git fetch --all; git lfs fetch --all
     V
     V  (rsync over ssh tunnel to client site)
     V
[remote_bare.repo]   <=== origin for remote client clones
     V
     V   (git clone from network location, checkout, fetch)
     V
Clone to Multiple Workspaces
```

This scheme works for us, allowing me to checkout various commits to the machines at our client site.  I am not pushing code back up the chain.

The problem are the LFS files.  running git lfs fetch --all on the local_bare.repo pulls the files into the .git/lfs folder.  And they are synched to the remote systems in the remote_bare.repo.  So that seems OK.

But when I clone from a client, the LFS files fail.  I'll get a smudge error, and if I set GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 I won't get an error, but I don't get the binary either (just the pointer).

I set the lfs.url to the remote_bare.repo (see below), and this doesn't seem to cause an error (unless it's why it won't  fetch the binaries)

So the big question is... when I clone from the remote_bare.repo (on the network) how do I instruct the client git-lfs to fetch the binaries from that repo's lfs\objects folder?

git lfs env:

```
Endpoint=file:///g:/<PATH>/test.git (auth=none)
LocalWorkingDir=C:\temp\test
LocalGitDir=C:\temp\test\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=C:\temp\test\.git
LocalMediaDir=C:\temp\test\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=C:\temp\_test\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=C:\temp\test\.git\lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
GIT_EXEC_PATH=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```